# How can I change simple <element> to <element> with restriction in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have XSD like this :

```
<xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
       <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
       <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
       <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

How can I find **xs:element with name="A"** ? (1)

then Add restriction to it programmatically (2)

like this :

```
        <xs:element name="A">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="24"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="B">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
```

I have some XSD files that elements of it must rewrite and correct with new type and related restrictions so I need to find element first and then replace with correct data

Can anyone help me how write in C#?